# Requests Gzip HTTP download and write to disk

Tags: python-2.7, http, gzip, python-requests, zlib

I'm using the requests library and python 2.7 to download a gzipped text file from a web api. Using the code below, I'm able to successfully send a get request and, judging from the headers, receive a response in the formed of the gzip file.

I know Requests decompresses these files for you automatically if it detects from the header that the response is gzipped. I wanted to take that download in the form of a file stream and write the contents to disk for storage and future analysis.

When I get open the resulting file in my working directory however I get characters like this: —}}¶— Q@Ï 'õ

For reference, some of the response headers include 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Type': 'application/download', 'Accept-Encoding,User-Agent'

Am I wrong to write in binary? Am I not encoding the text correctly(ie. could it be ASCII vs utf-8)? There is no apparent character encoding noted in the response headers.

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url, paramDict, stream=True)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

with open(outName, 'wb') as out_file:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        out_file.write(chunk)
```

**EDIT 3.30.2016**:
    Now I've changed my code a little bit to utilize gzipstream library. I tried using the stream to read the entirety of the Gzipped text file that is in my response content:

```
with open(outName, 'wb') as out_file, GzipStreamFile(response.content) as fileStream:
    streamContent = fileStream.read()
    out_file.write(streamContent)
```

I then received this error: 
out_file.write(streamContent)
AttributeError: '_GzipStreamFile' object has no attribute 'close'

The output was an empty text file with the file name as anticipated. Do I need to initialize my streamContent variable outside of the `with` block so that it doesn't automatically try to call a close method at the end of the block?

**EDIT 4.1.2016** Just thought I'd clarify that this DOES NOT have to be a stream, that was just one solution I encountered. I just want to make a daily request for this gzipped file and have it saved locally in plaintext

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url, paramDict)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

data = zlib.decompress(response.content, zlib.MAX_WBITS|32)

with open('outFileName.txt','w') as outFile:
    outFile.write(data)
```

Here is the code that I wrote that ended up working. It is as sigmavirus said: the file was gzipped to begin with. I knew this fact, but did not describe it clearly enough apparently as I kept read/writing the gzipped bytes.

Using the zlib module, I was able to decompress the content of the response all at one time into the data variable; I then wrote that variable containing the decompressed data into a file.

I'm not sure if this is the best or most pythonic way to do this, but it worked. If anyone can enlighten me as to why I cannot `gzip.open` this content (perhaps I needed to use an alternative method, I tried gzipstream library to no avail), I would appreciate any explanations, but I do consider this question answered.

Thanks to everyone who helped me, even if you didn't have the solution, you helped encourage me to persevere!

Comment: Maybe that you havo to add a .decode("utf-8") to "data" when you write it.

Answer (score 3):

So the combination here of `stream=True` and `iter_content` is what is causing your problems. What you might want to do is something akin to this (to preserve the streaming behaviour):

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url, params=paramDict, stream=True)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

raw = response.raw
with open(outName, 'wb') as out_file
    while True:
        chunk = raw.read(1024, decode_content=True)
        if not chunk:
            break
        out_file.write(chunk)
```

Note that you still want to use bytes because you haven't determined the character encoding of the content so you still have bytes but you're no longer dealing with the gzipped bytes.

Comment: this ran, but it still only wrote a file with non-human-readable characters. Should I use it with the gzipstream library and try to un-gzip the stream as I read it right before the `if not chunk` block?

Comment: Can you check `response.headers` for a `Content-Encoding` header and let me know what it says please?

Comment: `{'Content-Length': '7811', 'Via': 'CONNECTION-INFO removed by jaxas', 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=****.txt.gz', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding,User-Agent', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=3, max=100', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Date': 'Fri, 01 Apr ', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Content-Type': 'application/download'}`  Here are the response headers. I'm thinking I should read the response.raw into an StringIO buffer and then decode it from that object using zlib instead. I can only make this request a few times a day

Comment: Hm, so I think what's happening is that they're sending you a gzipped text file in the first place. If you look at the Content-Disposition header, the filename ends with `.txt.gz` this means that the file is gzipped. So the file you're saving on disk is a gzipped file. You could do what you describe using what I'm describing and you'll get your file as you expect it.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting the raw socket stream which is stripping of the chunk transfer encoding but leaving the content coding intact. In other words: What you've got there is pretty certainly the gzipped content. The  presence of the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header is a strong indicator for that, as http clients are required to remove it should they remove the content coding.

One way to eliminate this would be to send an empty `Accept-Encoding` header among the request to indicate no encoding were acceptable. If the API is RFC compliant, you should receive an uncompressed response. The other way would be to decompress the stream yourself. I believe this cannot be done natively by the gzip and zlib modules. However, the [gzipstream](https://github.com/Smerity/gzipstream) lib should give you a start.

Comment: I'm going to try turning off the stream to see if accessing the response instead of the raw socket will allow Requests to decompress the response content. I will also try turning the stream=True back on and then using the gzipstream lib to handle the content. Additionally, I'm not sure if this API is RFC compliant as it's for an obscure game and is poorly documented and maintained. Is there any way to check?

Comment: @jaxas I know of a testbed for http clients but I am not aware of any validation service for API endpoints, sorry. The only way to check in this regard were to fire a manipulated request and see for the result. One thing that came to my mind later on: If you are on a linux/unix system, there is the `file` command, checking for type and content of a file. That one would return something akin to "gzip compressed data" if it really is gzipped. Oh, and writing in binary mode is the absolutely right thing to do.